Is there any functions to get the states of `Background data` and `Unrestricted mobile data usage` on Android 15?
User can disable the app connects the network when the app is running in background. 
The picture shows two slide buttons. If user disable "Background data", the app cannot download data from network.
I want to know how to check this condition? Is there any functions to get the states of Background data and Unrestricted mobile data usage?

You can read the page https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/behavior-changes-all?hl=zh-cn
and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationStartInfo#wasForceStopped(). I hope that will help you.
